# XSLT - Wrapping up of string after delimiter count 5 (e.g. 5 "|")

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am newbie in XSLT. I need to wrap up a long string after certain number of delimiter occurs.
Example of such a string is : -

Jason|Michael|John|James|Rick|Paul|JenYee|Ray|Eliza|Shilpa|Abhishek|Patrick|Brent|Kevin|Jim

I don't want to use template for this due to some constraints.

However if its not possible - i am ok with the template.

The output should be like this:
                                                                                            Line 1: Jason|Michael|John|James|Rick|                                                     Line 2: Paul|JenYee|Ray|Eliza|Shilpa|                                                          Line 3: Abhishek|Patrick|Brent|Kevin|Jim

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "wrap up". You want to *truncate* the string after 5 delimiters? You gave a sample input string above; please show what the output for that string would be.

Comment: Line 1: Jason|Michael|John|James|Rick|                             Line 2: Paul|JenYee|Ray|Eliza|Shilpa|                              Line 3: Abhishek|Patrick|Brent|Kevin|Jim

Comment: OK, you want to *wrap* the string after 5 delimiters. In other words, you want to output all the parts of the string, not just the first 5, but split into multiple lines. Looks like both of those who answered so far misunderstood what you wanted. Suggestion: edit your question, so you can show the desired output, formatted in a way that's easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

Use this recursive templates:

```
<xsl:template name="beforeSeparators">
  <xsl:param name="start"/>
  <xsl:param name="rest"/>
  <xsl:param name="separator"/>
  <xsl:param name="count"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$count &lt;= 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="$start"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($rest,$separator)">
      <xsl:call-template name="beforeSeparators">
        <xsl:with-param name="start" select="concat($start,substring-before($rest,$separator),$separator)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="substring-after($rest,$separator)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($start,$rest)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="wrap">
  <xsl:param name="str"/>
  <xsl:param name="separator"/>
  <xsl:param name="separatorsPerLine"/>
  <xsl:variable name="line">
    <xsl:call-template name="beforeSeparators">
      <xsl:with-param name="start" select="''"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="$str"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$separatorsPerLine"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($line,'&#x0d;&#x0a;')"/>
  <xsl:if test="string-length($line) &lt; string-length($str)">
    <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,string-length($line))"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="separatorsPerLine" select="$separatorsPerLine"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

called like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="wrap">
  <xsl:with-param name="str" select="'Jason|Michael|John|James|Rick|Paul|JenYee|Ray|Eliza|Shilpa|Abhishek|Patrick|Brent|Kevin|Jim'"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="separatorsPerLine" select="5"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

produces:

```
Jason|Michael|John|James|Rick|
Paul|JenYee|Ray|Eliza|Shilpa|
Abhishek|Patrick|Brent|Kevin|
```

Here is my complete test XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template name="beforeSeparators">
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:param name="rest"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator"/>
    <xsl:param name="count"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$count &lt;= 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="$start"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains($rest,$separator)">
        <xsl:call-template name="beforeSeparators">
          <xsl:with-param name="start" select="concat($start,substring-before($rest,$separator),$separator)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="substring-after($rest,$separator)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($start,$rest)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="wrap">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator"/>
    <xsl:param name="separatorsPerLine"/>
    <xsl:variable name="line">
      <xsl:call-template name="beforeSeparators">
        <xsl:with-param name="start" select="''"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="$str"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$separatorsPerLine"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($line,'&#x0d;&#x0a;')"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($line) &lt; string-length($str)">
      <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,string-length($line)+1)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="separatorsPerLine" select="$separatorsPerLine"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="'Jason|Michael|John|James|Rick|Paul|JenYee|Ray|Eliza|Shilpa|Abhishek|Patrick|Brent|Kevin|'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="separatorsPerLine" select="5"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(it just translate a fixed string,, so it can be applied to any XML)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without using template ?

Comment: @apratik: no - you need recursion, and hence you need a template that can call itself

Comment: I fixed my answer based on your comments answering Lars

Comment: Have you checked the output - i have used the same code and got the value as blank. :-(

Comment: Yes, I did check the output - it is as in my answer. I posted complete test XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you could use `tokenize()`.

Example (`$input` is the string in your question):

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize($input,'\|')[5 >= position()]" separator="|"/>
```

This will produce: `Jason|Michael|John|James|Rick`

Comment: I have constraint to use only XSLT1.0 . Tha's the problem.